# Destructor is called multiple times and out of place

Tags: c++, memory-management

The problem in ma Model class is with processing each mesh it's composed of. When it consists of 7 meshes, firstly the destructor is called 21 times. And after exiting the program it's called 14 times. Really don't know what I am doing wrong. I was able to trach the problem to this particular pice of code.

```
void Model::processNode(aiNode *node, const aiScene *scene) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++) {
        aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
        mMeshes.push_back(processMesh(mesh, scene));
    }
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++) {
        processNode(node->mChildren[i], scene);
    }
}
```

mMeshes is a private vector of meshes for single Model object.

Edit:

To clarify, the problem is that when the destructor of Mesh class is not commented out, it completely destroys everything in mMeshes vector. This is the destructor of Mesh

```
Mesh::~Mesh () {
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &mVAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS, mVBOs);
}
```

this is the vector of Meshes.

```
std::vector<Vertex> mVertices;
```

and header of processNode, it just creates new mesh and returns it to the vector.

```
Mesh Model::processMesh(aiMesh *mesh, const aiScene *scene);
```

Comment: What is `mMeshes`? What does `processMesh` do? What do `processNode` do? There's probably some copying going on that you don't notice.

Comment: You probably forgot to decorate your copy constructor.

Comment: `mMeshes.push_back(processMesh(mesh, scene));` that's copy-city right there.

Comment: We can't really help you if you haven't posted declarations of any of these classes nor their destructors you are asking about.

Comment: Why do you assume that you are doing something *wrong*? Does the code not work? It looks like you're just creating lots of temporaries, which the compiler is correctly emitting code to clean up. This isn't terribly efficient, but it isn't *wrong* either.

Comment: Sorry, the mMeshes is std::vector<Mesh> mMeshes. This is what destructor of Mesh looks like.
`Mesh::~Mesh () {
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &mVAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS, mVBOs);
}`
The thins is, if I uncomment this, the no model will be displayed because they got destroyed in the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not reserve enough memory in the vector to accommodate new elements then the vector can reallocates memory when a new element is added. In this case it allocates a new extend of memory and copies all elements from the old extent of memory to the new one. So after copying the elements to the new place the elements in the old place are deleted.  Also the member function `push_back` can deal with a temporary object that will be copied to the vector and after that will be deleted.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct A
{
    std::string s;
    A(const std::string &s) : s(s)
    {
        std::cout << "Object " << this->s << " is created" << std::endl; 
    }

    A( const A &a ) : s( "copy of " + a.s )
    {
        std::cout << "A " << this->s << " is created" << std::endl;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "Object " << s << " is deleted" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        std::vector<A> v;

        v.push_back(A("A"));
        v.push_back(A("B"));
        v.push_back(A("C"));
    }
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Object A is created
A copy of A is created
Object A is deleted
Object B is created
A copy of copy of A is created
Object copy of A is deleted
A copy of B is created
Object B is deleted
Object C is created
A copy of copy of copy of A is created
A copy of copy of B is created
Object copy of copy of A is deleted
Object copy of B is deleted
A copy of C is created
Object C is deleted
Object copy of copy of copy of A is deleted
Object copy of copy of B is deleted
Object copy of C is deleted
```

Comment: ok even after reserving space in the vector of Meshes, it still deletes them in a really weird way. This is the output I get if I put print in destructor and at the end of the first for loop in processNode function.

Del. mesh |
Processed |
Del. mesh |
Del. mesh |
Processed |
Del. mesh |
Del. mesh |
Del. mesh |
Processed | 
Del. mesh |
Processed |
Del. mesh |
Del. mesh |
Del. mesh |
Del. mesh |
Del. mesh |
Processed |
Del. mesh |
Processed |
Del. mesh |
Processed |
Del. mesh |
Del. mesh |
Del. mesh |
Del. mesh |
Del. mesh |
Del. mesh |
Del. mesh |